# jquery text | on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone tell me how this animation is working "centered one".See [a link](http://www.stern.nyu.edu/).I don't know where to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split up the text into spans

```
<spans class="highlightOnHover">
```

Then use some jQuery to highlight this

```
$(".highlghtOnHover").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

Comment: Heh why the downvote? Please comment so we can improve (and improve answers).

Comment: @FAIQNASEEM inbetween the span tags.